# Classe filha não reconhece variavel protected da classe mãe

Tags: php

Tenho uma classe usuario que não enxerga variavel protected da classe que ela herda o código é o seguinte

```
abstract class Model{

    protected $conn;

    public function __construct(){
        $conn = Connect::getConnection();
    }
}
```

Classe filha

```
class Usuario extends Model{

    public function testaConexao(){
        if($this->conn)
            return 'sucesso';
        else
            return 'falha';
    }
}
```

chamada

```
$user = new Usuario();
echo $user->testaConexao();
//saida: falha
```

Gerando um log dentro do construtor de Model a variável $conn é criada e é diferente de false. Mas quando tento utilizá-la na classe filha ja não reconhece, retorna null usando $this->conn;

Answer (score 0):

Erro bobo, esqueci de referenciar com $this, deve ser `$this->conn = Connect::getConnection();` dentro do construtor do Model.

```
abstract class Model{

    protected $conn;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->conn = Connect::getConnection();
    }
}
```